# Adding column of filename to all the files in a directory

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I have a set of 291 `csv` files in a directory. What I want to do is to append a column to the start of the files, where the contents of that column is the filename. So like:

```
filename, ID, Mag, Magerr, RA, Decl, MJD, Blend
CSSJ235751.9+065855, 12302, 223, 34, 23.423, 23.54, 8723, 0,
```

where filename is the new column I would like to add. And I want to this to all the files i have in the directory. I was thinking of using `awk` or `sed` possibly for this, but I'm not very familiar with them.

I tried:

```
awk '{print "CSSJ235751.9+065855,"$0}' CSSJ235751.9+065855.csv > modCSSJ235751.9+065855.csv;
```

which worked for one. By how would I generalize so I can do all the files at once?

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /path/to/csvFiles
for f in *.csv ; do
   awk -v fName="${f%.csv}" '{printf("%s,%s\n", (FNR==1 ? "filename" : fName), $0)}' "$f" > mod"$f"
done
```

Be sure to work on a copy of your data.

IHTH

Comment: I have amended script to put "filename" on the first line AND to strip off the `.csv` extension for the value of `fName` that will be used by `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS=", " }
FNR == 1 {
    fname = FILENAME
    out = "mod" FILENAME
    sub(/\.csv$/,"",1,fname)
    print "filename", $0 > out
    next
}
{ print fname, $0 > out }
' *.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Gee, appending to the start of each line is just simple enough for sed.

```
for f in *.csv
do
    sed "1 s/^/filename,/; 2,$ s/^/${f%.*},/" f > f.new
    mv f f.old && mv f.new f
done
```

Per comments above, the filename `f` is expanded to remove the .csv extension.  When you're satisfied you have what you want, you can delete *.old.  Meanwhile, if you mess up, you can restore the originals.