# how to extract same columns and merge together from several excels

Tags: linux

I have a directory named as "annotation", in which there are multiple sub-directory named with sample ID such as "A21","B32","D54" and so on. For example in one sub-directory named as "A21", there will be one excel file named as "A21.snp.annotation.xls", in which I would like to extract the first four columns,the 21th and 72th columns.

After six columns were extracted, the file would be presented in the similar ways as follows:

```
chr  pos ref alt gene  snp
1    123 A   T   gene1 rs111
2    234 C   G   gene2 rs222
```

the last column "snp" can be used as an index for different samples, so I would like to merge different samples using "snp" as index, the final file would be presented in the following way:

```
snp A21  B32 D54
rs111 AT AT  TT 
rs222 CG CC  GG
```

Then I would like to count the number of ref allele,  the final file would be presented as

```
snp A21  B32 D54
rs111 1  1   0 
rs222 1  2   0
```

Comment: Contrary to what you seem to believe, StackOverflow isn't a free coding service (or exam answering service). You're expected to show your code, along with relevant sample inputs, expected outputs (which you have!), actual error msgs as well as your comments about where you are stuck. Please show your best effort to solve this problem and people may be able to help you. Good luck.

Comment: Actually, I do not how to handle multiple files in linux. All that I can think of is   : for sub-directories in directory, cd sub-directory, awk ' {print $1/t$2/t$3/t$4/t$21$/t$72} '. Then I can use R to merge if the linux is not working for me. If anyone can show me how to handle multiple files and extract the desired columns in linux, I can probably manage the rest.

Comment: A. You're looking to extract data from Excel files? How is this a linux problem? Do you know how to use `File-SaveAs->TabDelimited`? You can select the columns you want into a separate worksheet and then sav just that sheet. B. "I do not how to handle multiple files in linux". This doesn't seem to be mentioned in your original Q AND how do you think Linux and Excel can be combined to solve the problem? ....

Comment: C. Please consider editing your Q so readers can understand where you are stuck, reading 1 unified story, rather than having to read comments. Insert yoiur awk code, and show its output, VS your required output. D. AND you're bringing `R` into this? There may be an `R` library that can parse Excel files, so I would recommend researching that first. For a general idea on how to process groups of files in Linux, see my answer at  http://stackoverflow.com/a/38401293/620097 .Good luck.